# Java concatenating integer values as a byte

Tags: java, java-me, argb

I have the following 4 integer values which represent ARGB:

```
int value1 = 0xFF;
int value2 = 68;
int value3 = 68;
int value4 = 68;
```

I would like to concatenate the values so they represent following:

```
int test = 0xFF686868;
```

My current approach is to use:

```
int test2 = 0xFF | value1 | value2 | value3;
```

But using this approach the integer values of test1 and test2 do not match, what am I doing wrong? I am limited to J2ME.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're almost there: all you need to do is shifting the individual bytes into position before `OR`-ing them together.

```
int test2 = (value1 << 24) | (value2 << 16) | (value3 << 8) | value4;
```

Don't forget to make your `68`s hex for the desired output of `0xFF686868`

```
int value2 = 0x68; // Add 0x to all three of the 68s
```

Comment: Could you explain why I must shift the bytes? Also, how would I convert 68 to 0x68? Thanks

Comment: @S-K' Think of shifting left as adding zeros to the right. In hex notation, a shift by 4 is the same as adding one zero to the end. Shifting by 24 adds 6 zeros, by 16 - 4 zeros, by 8 - 2 zeros. Since `OR`ing with zero yields the original number, shifting and `OR`ing bytes lets you construct a four-byte number.